# How does upstream and downstream handlers work in Netty?

Tags: java, netty

I'm new to [Netty](https://netty.io/) and don't really understand the flow of handlers in it. What I want to know is the difference between the `Upstream` and `Downstream` handlers.

- Why can't we intercept the message in downstream handlers as we do in
  upstream?
- Do downstream and upstream mean the same as in normal terms?

Answer (score 8):

The difference is that one handles incoming (upstream) and the other outgoing (downstream).
I think the event/message flow gets more clear after looking at the javadoc of [`ChannelPipeline`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html).

I should also note that upstream events will only get triggered by the IO-Thread so there is no need to synchronize field access in there if you use a new `ChannelUpstreamHandler` per `ChannelPipeline`. Downstream events can be triggered by any thread, so access to fields needs to be synchronized.

Comment: Thank you for replying... But what I don't understand is that in telnet application given in Jboss Netty site, it uses an upstream handler to print the message sent back from the server... But why aren't they using a downstream handler...? Could you please give an example for downstream handlers.....

Comment: Like I said upstream is for incomming which in fact is what it is in the example. And example for an downstream event would be an encoder that needs to encode your written object to a ChannelBuffer. For an example see https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3.2/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/oneone/OneToOneEncoder.java

Comment: So sorry to bother you again.. Could you please explain what is meant by IO Threads ? For an example, in the Telnet application,what is the way that the client side upstream handlers get triggered ? I think this is what I really don't understand....

Comment: As soon as a buffer was received it will fire an event which will get send to the ChannelPipeline. The ChannelPipeline will the handle it with its ChannelUpstreamHandler instances.

Comment: Thanx.. now I get it...But I still don't understand why upstream handler flow is shown as going out from the app in ChannelPipeline... could you please expalin that too ?

Comment: Its not showing as it goes out. I guess you think it does as it goes from bottom to top but thats not the case.. When you look in more detail you will noticed that upstream is triggered by Socket.read(..) which is incomming.

Comment: I was confused with this also, its tempting to see it as downloading and uploading a file. Its quite the opposite. See it as your laptop being on a mountain,Upstream Handlers will handle stuffs like decryption, decompression, decode  till they get to you and downstream the opposite.

Comment: In the next major version of Netty it will get called Inbound and Outbound, so hopefully less confusing.

Comment: Hi Norman, about the second part, when multiple threads are going to r/w a same handler field, no matter if it is inbound or outbound, it needs to be synchronized I think, unless like you said it is `new` every time a thread uses this handler (not distinguishing inhandler or outhandler).

Answer (score 4):

## Theoretical information

I think the ideas are being derived from network stacks.
Netty's *handler-pipeline* analogy is similar to OSI Network layer-stack. Take a look into how OSI network layer look like:
[image]

Think each *handler* as 'one layer', whole *pipeline* as 'one network stack', physical link as 'IO source' and User as 'application logic handler'. Using the same pipeline (stack), we need to do two functionalities:

1. Transmit data (**send data down**, when 'application logic handler' want to do something through 'IO source')
2. Receive data (**send data up**, when 'IO source' has some event, which might be interest of 'application logic handler').

So essentially same *pipeline* has to do two different things (receive the messages and send the messages back).

---

## Practical example

Let's consider a concrete example (a server with authentication and encryption), with 3 *handlers* making up a *pipeline*:
[image: Example Netty pipeline with 3 handlers]

Let's look at responsibility of each in-terms of receiving the messages

1. Encryption handler --> needs to receive `UpstreamEvent` from 'IO Source' and `DownstreamEvent` from 'Application Handler' or 'Auth Handler' in the above flows.
2. Auth handler --> needs to receive `UpstreamEvent` only from 'Encryption handler'.
3. Application handler -->  needs to receive `UpstreamEvent` from 'Auth Handler' only.

So, logically, each handler has to implement the following:

1. Encryption handler --> `ChannelUpstreamHandler` and `ChannelDownstreamHandler`
2. Auth handler --> `ChannelUpstreamHandler`
3. Application handler --> `ChannelUpstreamHandler`

So If you have a `ChannelPipeline`, with 3 handlers mentioned above,

- For incoming message: 'IO source'(0) initiates `UpstreamEvent` and Netty will forward the `UpstreamEvent` to (1) then (2) then optionally (3), since all 3 have implemented `ChannelUpstreamHandler`.
- When 'Application handler'(3) / 'Auth Handler'(2), wants to send status message back to client, then it'll initiate with `write` call (which creates `DownstreamEvent`). Netty will forward the `DownstreamEvent` to (1) (which is only one, before (3) and implemented `ChannelDownstreamHandler`).

So given the *pipeline* with *handlers*, when an `UpstreamEvent` is created (by 'IO source'), Netty will call all handlers in the pipeline in sequence from 1 to n,  which have implemented `ChannelUpstreamHandler` (*n* is number of handlers, in the above example *n* = 3). And when a `DownstreamEvent` is created (by user application code), Netty will call all handlers in the pipeline in sequence from *n* to *1*, which have implemented `ChannelDownstreamHandler`.

Since a class can implement two interfaces, a handler can be both `ChannelUpstreamHandler` and `ChannelDownstreamHandler`. Please note that all `UpstreamEvent` are created by 'IO Source' and all `DownstreamEvent` are created by user application logic.

---

## Examples of channel events

Examples of `UpstreamEvent`:

1. message received
2. channel opened
3. channel closed
4. exception raised by 'IO source'
5. write completed by 'IO source'
6. channel disconnected
7. ...

Examples of `DownstreamEvent`:

1. Write a message to channel
2. Bind to a port
3. connect to server address
4. ...

Hope it'll help you to answer "Why do we need two behaviours for handlers (upstream and downstream)", "How Netty solves the sending and receiving through `Downstream` and `Upstream`" and "How can we really use the constructs in real world application".

*Your answer ends here, for extra content, you can continue below.*

---

#### Regarding the above presented *handlers*

Let's look at responsibility of each of the above presented *handlers* in terms of forwarding the messages:

1. *Application handler* --> needs to forward messages to previous layers (should call `ctx.sendDownstream(e)` implicitly or explicitly)
2. *Auth handler* --> needs to forward messages to previous layers (for auth failure) and to next layers (for auth success). (should call `ctx.sendDownstream(e)` and `ctx.sendUpstream(e)` implicitly or explicitly)
3. *Encryption handler* --> needs to forward message to previous layers and next layers (should call `ctx.sendDownstream(e)` and `ctx.sendUpstream(e)` implicitly or explicitly).